# Generalizing a result of Kreisel on $\omega$-consistency

Tags: lo.logic, proof-theory

In  ([reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.philosophy.ox.ac.uk%2F__data%2Fassets%2Fpdf_file%2F0015%2F1194%2FSufficient_conditions.pdf&ei=7DAPVczxCoXfaqD_glg&usg=AFQjCNFrPLZT7E00XZ5-GjdmzvJ2Lwoqzw))The following result is attributed to Kreisel:

**Lemma1**(Kreisel) If $T$ is an $\omega$-consistent theory in the language of arithmetic and $\pi$ is a true $\Pi_1$ sentence, then $T+\pi$ is also $\omega$-consistent.

My question is:

**Question**: If $T$ is an $\omega$-consistent theory in the language of arithmetic, is $T+Th_{\Pi_1}(\mathbb{N})$ also $\omega$-consistent?  ($Th_{\Pi_1}(\mathbb{N})$ is the set of all true $\Pi_1$ sentences).

The best i could do is the following result:

**lemma2**) If $T\supset I\Sigma_1$ is an $\omega$-consistent theory in the language of arithmetic and $A$ an r.e. subset of $Th_{\Pi_1}(\mathbb{N})$, then $T+A$ is also
$\omega$-consistent.

**proof**:
if $T_1=T+A$  was $\omega$-inconsistent, then there was a sentence $\exists x \alpha(x)$ such that $T+A\vdash \exists x \alpha(x)$ and also $T+A\vdash \neg \alpha(\overline{n})$ (for all $n$).
Let $A=\{\pi_{i}\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. By the compactness theorem, there are indexes $j_{1},\ldots,j_{m}$ such that:
$T+\{ \pi_{j_{1}},\ldots,\pi_{j_{m}}\}\vdash \exists x \alpha(x)$.
It follows from conservation theorem([reference](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.compstat2004.cuni.cz%2F%7Ekrajicek%2Fsmorynski.pdf&ei=RjsPVYv_CY_3aor0gKgF&usg=AFQjCNF0y3C6S6X0z0_ViU6993GwAgn7Mw&sig2=JXr0dqT501lSJcC1foTefw), theorem 5.2.1) that  $T+con(T_{1})\vdash  \pi_{i}$ (for every $i\in \mathbb{N}$). Then
$T+con(T_{1})\vdash \exists x \alpha(x)$,
and by similar reason:
$T+con(T_{1})\vdash \neg \alpha(\overline{n})$  (for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$).
Then $T_1=T+con(T_{1})$ is an $\omega$-inconsistent theory and it contradicts the lemma1.

Comment: You want to use $\mathrm{Con}(Q+A)$, not $\mathrm{Con}(T_1)$; otherwise you’d need an additional (and unnecessary) assumption that $T$ itself is r.e. (Also, $I\Sigma_1$ is an overkill; you only need formalized $\Sigma_1$-completeness, for which $I\Delta_0+\mathit{EXP}$ is enough.) Basically, the argument amounts to the fact that an r.e. set of true $\Pi_1$ sentences is implied by a single true $\Pi_1$ sentence.

Comment: Yes Emil, your comment is completely correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The property does not hold in general.

First, I’ll recall some basic properties of $\omega$-consistency. Let $T\vdash_1\phi$ denote the relation that $\phi$ is derivable from $T$ using rules of first-order logic, and *unnested* instances of the $\omega$-rule.

1. If $T\vdash_1\phi$, then $\phi$ is derivable from $T$ using a *single* instance of the $\omega$-rule. In particular, $T$ is $\omega$-inconsistent if and only if $T\vdash_1\bot$.
2. If $T$ is r.e., then $T\vdash_1\phi$ is a $\Sigma_3$ property of $\phi$. Thus, the $\omega$-consistency of $T$ is a $\Pi_3$ statement.
3. On the other hand, $Q\vdash_1\phi$ for every true $\Sigma_3$ sentence $\phi$: write $\phi=\exists x\,\forall y\,\psi(x,y)$, where $\psi\in\Sigma_1$, and fix $n\in\omega$ such that $\mathbb N\models\forall y\,\psi(\bar n,y)$. Then $Q\vdash\psi(\bar n,\bar m)$ for every $m$ by $\Sigma_1$-completeness of $Q$, hence $Q\vdash_1\forall y\,\psi(\bar n,y)$ using the $\omega$-rule.
4. Similarly, $Q+\mathrm{Th}_{\Pi_1}(\mathbb N)\vdash_1\phi$ for every true $\Sigma_4$ sentence $\phi$: this follows by the same argument as above, with $\psi\in\Sigma_2$.
5. If $T$ is an r.e. extension of $I\Delta_0+\mathit{EXP}$ (this can be negotiated down with a bit of care), then $T\vdash_1\phi$ satisfies the Bernays–Löb derivability conditions: that is, if we write $\Box_{T,1}\phi$ for the natural arithmetization of $T\vdash_1\phi$, we have

   - $T\vdash_1\phi\implies T\vdash_1\Box_{T,1}\phi$: this is a consequence of 2 and 3.
   - $T\vdash\Box_{T,1}(\phi\to\psi)\to(\Box_{T,1}\phi\to\Box_{T,1}\psi)$: we can concatenate two proofs.
   - $T\vdash\Box_{T,1}\phi\to\Box_{T,1}\Box_{T,1}\phi$; more generally, if $\psi\in\Sigma_3$, then $T\vdash\psi\to\Box_{T,1}\psi$. This follows by formalizing the argument in 3, using the ordinary formalized $\Sigma_1$-completeness of $Q$.

   See [1] for more information about the provability logic of $\vdash_1$ and related provability predicates.

Now, let $T_0$ be an $\omega$-consistent r.e. extension of $I\Delta_0+\mathit{EXP}$ (such as $I\Sigma_1$ or $\mathit{PA}$), and put

$$T=T_0+\Box_{T_0,1}\bot$$

(that is, $T_0$ + its own formalized $\omega$-inconsistency). The standard proof of the second Gödel incompleteness theorem using the derivability conditions shows that $T$ is $\omega$-consistent. On the other hand, $\neg\Box_{T_0,1}\bot$ is a true $\Pi_3$ sentence, hence

$$T_0+\mathrm{Th}_{\Pi_1}(\mathbb N)\vdash_1\neg\Box_{T_0,1}\bot$$

by 4, thus $T+\mathrm{Th}_{\Pi_1}(\mathbb N)$ is $\omega$-inconsistent.

---

Kreisel’s lemma can be strengthened in a different direction, namely it holds for a larger class of formulas than $\Pi_1$:

> **Proposition 1:** If $T\supseteq Q$ is $\omega$-consistent, and $\phi$ is a true $\Sigma_3$ sentence, then $T+\phi$ is $\omega$-consistent.

**Proof:** Otherwise $T+\phi\vdash_1\bot$, hence $T\vdash_1\neg\phi$. On the other hand, $Q\vdash_1\phi$ by property 3 above, hence $T\vdash_1\bot$, i.e., $T$ is $\omega$-inconsistent.

> **Corollary 2:** If $T\supseteq Q$ is $\omega$-consistent, and $A$ is an r.e. set of true $\Pi_2$ sentences, then $T+A$ is $\omega$-consistent.

**Proof:** We may assume $T\supseteq I\Delta_0+\mathit{EXP}$ by Proposition 2, as $I\Delta_0+\mathit{EXP}$ is a finitely axiomatizable true $\Pi_2$ theory. It suffices to find a true $\Pi_2$ (or $\Sigma_3$) sentence $\phi$ such that $T+\phi\vdash A$. So, let $\alpha(x)$ be a $\Sigma_1$ definition of $A$ in $\mathbb N$, and $\mathrm{Tr}_{\Pi_2}(x)$ a universal $\Pi_2$ formula. Then we can take $\phi=\forall x\,(\alpha(x)\to\mathrm{Tr}_{\Pi_2}(x))$.

Notice that both statements are optimal with respect to arithmetic complexity:

- The Proposition may fail for true $\Pi_3$ sentences $\phi$: for example, take the $\omega$-consistent theory $T=T_0+\Box_{T_0,1}\bot$ considered above, and $\phi=\neg\Box_{T_0,1}\bot$, which is a true $\Pi_3$ sentence. Then $T+\phi$ is inconsistent.
- The Corollary may fail for r.e. sets $A$ of true $\Sigma_2$ sentences: continuing the previous example, write $\phi=\forall x\,\psi(x)$ with $\psi\in\Sigma_2$, and put $A=\{\psi(\bar n):n\in\omega\}$. Then $T+A\vdash_1\phi$, while $\neg\phi\in T$, hence $T+A$ is $\omega$-inconsistent.

---

For yet another extension of Kreisel’s lemma, I recall that Smoryński proved that for any r.e. theory $T\supseteq Q$,
$$T\vdash_1\phi\iff\mathrm{Tr}_{\Sigma_3}(\mathbb N)+\mathrm{RFN}_T\vdash\phi,$$
where $\mathrm{RFN}_T$ is the uniform reflection principle for $T$: the schema
$$\forall x\:\bigl(\Box_T\psi(\dot x)\to\psi(x)\bigr)$$
for all formulas $\psi(x)$, where $\Box_T$ denotes the usual provability predicate for $T$. It is also known that if $T\supseteq Q$ is finite, then $Q+\mathrm{RFN}_T\equiv T+\mathrm{PA}$. Thus:

> **Proposition 3:** If $T\supseteq Q$ is $\omega$-consistent, then $T+I\Sigma_n$ is $\omega$-consistent for every $n\in\omega$.
>
> Moreover, if $S\subseteq T$ is r.e., and $\phi(x)$ is any formula, then $T+\forall x\,\bigl(\Box_S\phi(\dot x)\to\phi(x)\bigr)$ is $\omega$-consistent.

---

**References:**

[1] George Boolos, *The Logic of Provability*, Cambridge University Press 1993.

[2] Craig Smoryński, *Self-reference and modal logic*, Springer, 1985.

Comment: @PayamSeraji Did you know that you can upvote answers that you find to be helpful? Just click on the uparrow to the left of the answer. It is recommended for knowledgeable people to vote this way, to help the site identify informative questions and answers. (You can also vote on other questions and answers.) Also, it is possible to "accept" an answer, if you find it to satisfactorily answer your question, by clicking on the check symbol.

Comment: Dear Professor Hamkins, thanks for guidance and i thank you again for your answer to my previous question.

Comment: Nots: (1) All the results hold with $\mathrm{Diag}(\mathbb N,0,S,+,\cdot,\le)$ in place of $Q$. (2) Proposition 3 fails for infinite r.e. sets of $\Sigma_2$ consequences of PA. For example, $T=Q+\neg\mathrm{RFN_{PA}}(\Sigma_2)$ is $\omega$-consistent, but $T+\mathrm{Thm}_{\Sigma_2}(\mathrm{PA})$ is not.